# Which values $a,L$ satisfy $\frac{\int_0^{4π}e^{t}(\sin^{6}(at)+\cos^{4}(at))\,dt}{\int_0^{π}e^{t}(\sin^{6}(at)+\cos^{4}(at))\,dt}=L$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Which option(s) below have the values of $a$ and $L$ that satisfy the following equation?

$$\frac{\int_0^{4π}e^{t}(\sin^{6}(at)+\cos^{4}(at))\,dt}{\int_0^{π}e^{t}(\sin^{6}(at)+\cos^{4}(at))\,dt}=L$$

> Options:
>
> 1. $a=2$, $L=\frac{e^{4\pi}-1}{e^{\pi}-1}$
> 2. $a=4$, $L=\frac{e^{4\pi}-1}{e^{\pi}-1}$

Comment: That isn't clear

Comment: What's that division sign? And use \text{} for words

Comment: The first expression is divided by the second.  Please help me with the edit.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^{4π}e^{t}(\sin^{6}(at)+\cos^{4}(at))\,dt
&=\sum_{k=0}^3 \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)π}e^{t}(\sin^{6}(at)+\cos^{4}(at))\,dt\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^3 \int_{0}^{π}e^{t+k\pi}(\sin^{6}(a(t+k\pi))+\cos^{4}(a(t+k\pi)))\,dt\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^3 e^{k\pi}\int_{0}^{π}e^{t}(\sin^{6}(at))+\cos^{4}(at)))\,dt
\qquad\text{(if a is an even integer)}\\
&=(\sum_{k=0}^3 e^{k\pi})\int_{0}^{π}e^{t}(\sin^{6}(at))+\cos^{4}(at)))\,dt\\
&=\dfrac{e^{4\pi}-1}{e^{\pi}-1}\int_{0}^{π}e^{t}(\sin^{6}(at))+\cos^{4}(at)))\,dt
\end{array}
$

so

$\dfrac{\int_0^{4π}e^{t}(\sin^{6}(at)+\cos^{4}(at))\,dt}
{\int_0^{π}e^{t}(\sin^{6}(at)+\cos^{4}(at))\,dt}
=\dfrac{e^{4\pi}-1}{e^{\pi}-1}
$
for
$a$ any even integer.

So both possibilities are true.

Answer (score 0):

Hint use $\sin(x)=R(e^{ix}),\cos(x)=I(e^{ix})$ or $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i},\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$